# Re-render the component when tab is clicked

Tags: react-native, redux, react-navigation

I am using react-navigation for tab navigation in my react-native app. I have four tabs. When I move from Tab A to Tab B, I am able to see Tab B. When I go back to Tab A and then again to Tab B without any changes, I am able to see Tab B.

But when I go back to Tab A, make some change which will affect display in Tab B, then click Tab B, I get an empty Tab B. My guess about what is happening is, when Tab A data is refreshed, it tries to update Tab B component. But since Tab B component is not part of the view, it empties it out.

Is there any way to re-render Tab B component when I click Tab B? Right now, there is no re-render. It just shows whatever is there an empty list.

The code within Tab A and Tab B is irrelevant. The only thing that matters is when Tab A updates some data in redux, Tab B re-renders but since Tab B is not in view, it is sort of empty! If I could re-render when the tab is clicked, I expect the view to work fine. How do I re-render on tab click?

[image]

Comment: If you are using a `FlatList` in Tab B, bear in mind that sometimes you need to pass `extraData={this.state}` as a prop. Otherwise it won't re-render when there is a state change.

Comment: I got around it by using FlatList instead of ListView. So closing this question as it is no longer reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

I would say check your reducer. Is it possible that when you update the state because of changes in Tab A you flush what Tab B needs?